# new JSONObject(somestring) fills the object with nulls

Tags: android, json

I have a string that i am fetching from a website. It is formatted as JSON.
I am doing new `JSONObject(jsonformattedstring)`. It has `JSONArray`(s) and some of it's items are null although the original string is valid and does not has nulls.

Here is a sample of the string: (The real string is much larger)

```
{"courses": [{"id": 1, "name":"X1"}, {"id": 2, "name":"Y1"}],
"rooms": [{"id": 1, "name":"X2"}, {"id": 2, "name":"Y2"}]}
```

`new JSONObject(str)` returns:

```
{"courses": [null, {"id": 2, "name":"Y1"}],
"rooms": [{"id": 1, "name":"X2"}, {"id": 2, "name":"Y2"}]}
```

The code runs as part of an Android app.
Why does this happen?
Is there a better option to create the `JSONObject`?

**This happens occasionally.**

Comment: I think your website's database is being modified. And there's a null Course object being appended to a list